# PHP POST data in ASCII instead of UTF8

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, utf-8

I have got problem with coding after sending data by POST from form.

When I am using special polish characters like ą, ć, ę, ł, ń etc. I am getting ? instead of proper character. I am struggling with it already third day and cannot find the problem.

Website is using UTF8 and all files are in UTF8. The form is sending data using AJAX and getting response using output buffer (ob). When I am checking headers in Chrome everything is alright. So it looks like something is happening with jQuery/Ajax/ob?

My all functions which are used for jQuery/Ajax/ob:

**jQuery**:

```
function ajaxForm(oform,ni,wt,nhi) {
    if (wt==''||wt==undefined) {
        if (oform.id=='theLongForm') {
            // time out based on the form id
            wt=120000;
        } else if (document.forms[oform.id].timeout) {
            // use the specific time out setting
            wt=document.forms[oform.id].timeout.value;
        } else {
            // default time out setting
            wt=10000;
        }
    }
    if (ni==''||ni==undefined) ni=false;
    if (nhi==''||nhi==undefined) nhi=false;
    if (ni!=true) showIndicator();
    $('#'+oform.id).ajaxSubmit({
        url: oform.action,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'xml',
        timeout: wt,
        error: function(){
            document.forms[oform.id].ajax.value='x';
            $('#'+oform.id).submit();

        },
        success: function(xml){
            if (processResult(xml)) {
                if (nhi!=true) $("#indicator").hide(200);
            }
        }
    });
    return false
}
```

**PHP:**

```
function outputAjaxHeader() {
    global $ajaxRequest,$doneAjaxHeader;
    if ($ajaxRequest && !$doneAjaxHeader) {
        // output ajax XML header
        header('Content-type: text/xml; charset: utf-8');
        print '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' . "\n";
        print '<items>' . "\n";
        $doneAjaxHeader = true;
    }
}

function outputAjaxItemStart($elem,$option='general',$full=false) {
    global $ajaxRequest;
    if ($ajaxRequest) {
        print "\t" . '<item>' . "\n";
        print "\t\t" . '<name>'.($full?'':'#').$elem.'</name>' . "\n";
        print "\t\t" . '<option>'.$option.'</option>' . "\n";
        print "\t\t" . '<data><![CDATA[';
        ob_start();
    }
}

function outputAjaxItemEnd() {
    global $ajaxRequest;
    if ($ajaxRequest) {
        $buffer = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        print $buffer;
        print ']]>' . '</data>' . "\n";
        print "\t" . '</item>' . "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try wrapping your output variables in utf8_encode()?

Comment: to your form action url, append: `?utf8=✓`. Also, you should probably set a `header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` on the page you see `?` instead of valid utf-8 characters.

Comment: @gunnx: yes, I tried with utf8_encode() and still nothing

Comment: @Prasanth: how ?utf8 could help in that? I have got set header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8')

Comment: the other thing which I found is that when I will change dataType: 'xml' to dataType: 'json' then it will start working, but I need it to working with xml ;/

Comment: I also found that this problem is only with polish letters

Comment: Also make sure that "default_encoding" in your PHP Ini file is set to "utf-8". To safe yourself much trouble, rule of thumb should be to ALLWAYS use utf-8 in any application, front and back, database, whereever. If you dont do this, you will quickly loose yourself in a constant search on where your encoding breaks... (been there did that ;) )

Comment: btw: Json works because it implicitly forces an encoding (Unicode?) and thus works around a part of your encoding troubles.

Comment: I have added init_set('default_charset', 'utf-8') but this is still not working ;/